# Show whether $ x^3$ is $O(g(x))$ where $g(x)=x^2 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I know that $x^3$ is $O(x^3)$ or any exponent higher than 3, but how do I show mathematically that $x^3$ is not $O(x^2)$?

Comment: Well, how do you know your first statement is true, e.g. what are the definitions here?

Comment: One way: using proof by contradiction. Second way: use the other definition, when you check the limit of $\frac{x^2}{x^3}$ and shows that $x^3$ can't be less or equal to $x^2$ multiple by a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show that it's NOT the case that $x^3=O(x^2)$, then you are showing that $x^2=o(x^3)$, or in other words, that $x^2$ is "little-oh" of $x^3$, which communicates that $x^2$ is of a smaller order of growth than $x^3$.

As gimusi has noted, you could show $x^2=o(x^3)$ via limits as follows

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^3}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3x^2}{2x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{6x}{2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{6}{2}x=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}3x=3\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x=3\cdot \infty =\infty$$

*Note the use of of L'Hopital's Rule since $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^3}{x^2}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ in the beginning

---

We could also show this using the definition of "big-oh." Consider that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ iff there exists constants $c,k$ such that $|f(x)| \le c \cdot |g(x)|$ for all $x>k$.

Let $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x^2$ and assume $x^3=O(x^2)$. Hence, by definition of big-oh, there exists constants $c,k$ such that

$$|x^3|\le c \cdot |x^2|$$

for all $x>k$. Note that $x^2>0$ and $x^3>0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, so we can remove the absolute value signs, having

$$x^3 \le c \cdot x^2$$

Now,

$$\frac{1}{x^2}x^3\le c \cdot x^2\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow x \le c$$

By the trichotomy law, for constants $c,k$ we know either $c=k$, $c<k$, or $k<c$.

**Case i. $c=k$**

By substitution we have $x \le k$. But we already stated $x>k$. Hence, we have contradiction.

**Case ii. $c<k$**

If $c<k$ and $x \le c$, we have $x < k$. But we already stated $x>k$. Hence, we have contradiction.

**Case iii. $k<c$**

Recall that $x \le c$ for ALL $x>k$. So whenever $x>c>k$, we have a contradiction.

Thus, if we assume $x^3=O(x^2)$, then in all cases we have a contradiction. Therefore, it is NOT the case that $x^3=O(x^2)$, and it is true that $x^2=o(x^3)$.

Comment: I don't need to show that $x^2 = O(x^3)$, but your explanation was helpful. One thing I don't understand too clearly is what the conclusion that $x < c$ really indicates. Does this mean that for some values of $c$, $f(x)$ is not less than or equal to $C \times g(x)$?

Comment: From what I understand, you want to show that $x^3$ is NOT $O(x^2)$... that is same exact thing as saying $x^2=o(x^3)$. In other words, the two statements are logically equivalent, so I was using them interchangeably.

Comment: $c$ is a constant real number. The assumption of the proof (which was shown to be false), says that as long you multiply $g(x)$ by some constant real number, $c$, then $f(x)$ will always be less than or equal to $c \cdot g(x)$, no matter how big $x$ is. What you end up showing in the end is that... it doesn't matter what value of $c$ you multiply $g(x)$ with, because as $x$ gets bigger and bigger, $f(x)$ will eventually be greater than $c \cdot g(x)$

Comment: So it implies that $C \times g(x)$ might be bigger with some values of $x$ and some values of $C$ in this case, but it won't be the case with bigger values of $x$. For the big O-notation, it has to hold true for all values of $x$. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Simply recall the [definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and note that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^3}{x^2}= \infty$$

Comment: Is there a way to prove without calculus?

Comment: By definition we need to consider a limit, in this case it is trivial since $x^3\x^2=x\to \infty$.

Comment: The definition of big-oh is not a limit, although in many cases you can use limits to quickly compare orders of growth. See my post above for an answer using a definition of big-oh.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^3 = O(x^2)$,
then there is a $c > 0$ and an $x_0$ such that
$x^3 < cx^2$ for $x > x_0$.

But this implies that
$x < c$ which is false for
$x > \max(c, x_0)$.

Therefore
$x^3 \ne O(x^2)$,
or
$x^3 \not\in O(x^2)$.